# Programmatically detect whether a display is attached to the computer or not

Tags: windows, display, logging, event-log

I have an unattended computer that runs software on a screen basically 24/7, and I'd like to be able to detect if the display has lost power or otherwise isn't detected by the computer.

The Windows Event Log seems to have the capabilities I'm looking for, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't automatically log this information.  Would I need to write a script that periodically checks and manually logs to the Windows Event Log the display status?  Or is it buried in there somewhere and I just don't know where?

And are there other alternatives for logging the status of my attached displays?

thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not seem to log monitor-related power events,
so you will indeed need to write a script or a program to
detect the status of the monitor.

Note that if the problem is that of the monitor entering
power-saving mode, this can be avoided by setting it to
never sleep in Power Options or monitor OSD.

To detect the primary monitor's presence in PowerShell,
you might be able to use the expression:

```
(Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi).Active
```

A program can do
[Registering for Power Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/registering-for-power-events?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
which might enable it to listen to the GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON
broadcast message.

You may also use code such as is found in the post
[How to check PC monitor is turned on or off any tool or event viewer in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652304/how-to-check-pc-monitor-is-turned-on-or-off-any-tool-or-event-viewer-in-windows)
in order to listen to the
[WM_POWERBROADCAST message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/wm-powerbroadcast?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

The
[GetDevicePowerState function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getdevicepowerstate?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
might work for the monitor, but is said to be unreliable.

Another source of inspiration might be found in Github
[Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/tree/master).

Note that all these methods have undocumented limitations.
Some may work for system-caused events, but not for manually turning
off/on the monitor etc.
You will have to test and see.

If you would have any programming questions, the right forum
for that is
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).